# Concatenate two 64bit integer and store it into a uint8_t array of [16]

Tags: c, concatenation

I want to concatenate a 64bit integer len_A with a 64bit integer len_C and store it into a uint8_t buffer[16]. But I couldnt do it even it I have assign len_A as (uint8_t *) len_A and len_C (uint8_t *) len_C.

The warning message was: cast to pointer from integer of different size

```
uint64_t len_A
uint64_t len_C
uint8_t buffer[16] = { 0 };

for (k = 7, l = 0; k >= 0 && l <= 7; k--, l++) {
    buffer[k] = buffer[k] ^ ((uint8_t *) len_A)[l];
}
for (k = 15, l = 0; k >= 8 && l <= 7; k--, l++) {
    buffer[k] = buffer[k] ^ ((uint8_t *) len_C)[l];
}
```

I've also done it in another way:

```
for (k = 15; k >= 0; k--) {
    if(k==0){
        buffer[k] = buffer[k] ^ (len_A && 0xff); // lowest byte 0 len_A
    }
    if(k!=0){
        buffer[k] = buffer[k] ^ ((len_A >> 8*k) & 0xff); // byte no 2 of len_A
    }
}
k=15;
for (k = 15; k>=7; k--) {
    if(k==0){
        buffer[k] = buffer[k] ^ (len_C && 0xff); // lowest byte 0 len_A
        }
    if(k!=0){
        buffer[k] = buffer[k] ^ ((len_C >> 8*k) & 0xff); // byte no 2 of len_A
    }
}
```

But still the compiler seems to point to an unknown address and giving the wrong results.

Are there any other options?

Comment: People copying numeric types into byte buffers are often about to store them or pass them to another system (possibly a completely different architecture).  If this is the case, then you need to be careful about 'endianness' (which end the most significant byte goes) - the memcpy and pointer-games solutions will only give you one layout, which might not actually be the one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is curious that you use the xor operator. It will work OK if (because) the target area is already zero, but it seems a little circuitous; you should be using plain assignment.  Notationally, there is also a `^=` operator that could be used to simplify the last proposed assignment to:

```
buffer[k] ^= ((len_C >> 8*k) & 0xFF);
```

(though the `^` should be omitted in this context).

Your problem in the first example is that you needed `((uint8_t *) &len_A)[l]` (and no xor).

```
uint64_t len_A;
uint64_t len_C;
uint8_t buffer[16] = { 0 };

for (k = 7, l = 0; k >= 0 && l <= 7; k--, l++)
    buffer[k] = ((uint8_t *)&len_A)[l];
for (k = 15, l = 0; k >= 8 && l <= 7; k--, l++)
    buffer[k] = ((uint8_t *)&len_C)[l];
```

This copies the data bytes into the buffer in the reverse order that they're found in memory. Solutions using `memcpy()` won't do that reversal.

The loop controls are still more complex than necessary. You could simplify the code to:

```
for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--)
    buffer[k] = ((uint8_t *)&len_A)[7-k];
for (k = 15; k >= 8; k--)
    buffer[k] = ((uint8_t *)&len_C)[15-k];
```

In the second example, you'll be shifting by more bits than there are in the `len_A` which will lead to trouble; you need to shift by `((k - 8) * 8)`.  It *is* legal to shift by zero, so you don't need to special case that. I've adjusted the bounds on both loops.

```
for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--)
     buffer[k] = (len_A >> (8*k)) & 0xFF;
for (k = 15; k>= 8; k--)
     buffer[k] = (len_C >> (8*(k-8))) & 0xFF;
```

I note that this third pair of loops do not do the byte-order reversal, though that's easily fixed:

```
for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--)
     buffer[k] = (len_A >> (8*(8-k))) & 0xFF;
for (k = 15; k>= 8; k--)
     buffer[k] = (len_C >> (8*(15-k))) & 0xFF;
```

Here's some demonstration output and code.

```
A = 0x0123456789ABCDEF
C = 0x0F1E2D3C4B5A6978
Loops 1:  01 23 45 67 89 AB CD EF : 0F 1E 2D 3C 4B 5A 69 78 :
Loops 2:  01 23 45 67 89 AB CD EF : 0F 1E 2D 3C 4B 5A 69 78 :
Loops 3:  EF CD AB 89 67 45 23 01 : 78 69 5A 4B 3C 2D 1E 0F :
Loops 4:  00 01 23 45 67 89 AB CD : 0F 1E 2D 3C 4B 5A 69 78 :
```

Code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void dump_buffer(size_t n, uint8_t const *data)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf(" %.2X", data[i]);
        if (i % 8 == 7)
            printf(" :");
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t len_A = 0x0123456789ABCDEF;
    uint64_t len_C = 0x0F1E2D3C4B5A6978;
    uint8_t  buffer[16] = { 0 };

    printf("A = 0x%.16llX\nC = 0x%.16llX\n", len_A, len_C);

    for (int k = 7, l = 0; k >= 0 && l <= 7; k--, l++)
        buffer[k] = ((uint8_t *)&len_A)[l];
    for (int k = 15, l = 0; k >= 8 && l <= 7; k--, l++)
        buffer[k] = ((uint8_t *)&len_C)[l];

    printf("Loops 1: ");
    dump_buffer(sizeof(buffer), buffer);

    for (int k = 7; k >= 0; k--)
        buffer[k] = ((uint8_t *)&len_A)[7-k];
    for (int k = 15; k >= 8; k--)
        buffer[k] = ((uint8_t *)&len_C)[15-k];

    printf("Loops 2: ");
    dump_buffer(sizeof(buffer), buffer);

    for (int k = 7; k >= 0; k--)
        buffer[k] = (len_A >> (8*k)) & 0xFF;
    for (int k = 15; k>= 8; k--)
        buffer[k] = (len_C >> (8*(k-8))) & 0xFF;

    printf("Loops 3: ");
    dump_buffer(sizeof(buffer), buffer);

    for (int k = 7; k >= 0; k--)
        buffer[k] = (len_A >> (8*(8-k))) & 0xFF;
    for (int k = 15; k>= 8; k--)
        buffer[k] = (len_C >> (8*(15-k))) & 0xFF;

    printf("Loops 4: ");
    dump_buffer(sizeof(buffer), buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried with the loops method. And I went ahead with the loop 2 method. It works awesome! Thanks for the detailed advice! Now I really understand how it works. Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
memcpy(buffer, &len_A, sizeof(len_A));
memcpy(buffer + sizeof(len_A), &len_C, sizeof(len_C));
```

The first line copies sizeof(len_A) ( 8 ) bytes to &buffer[0].

The second line copies sizeof(len_C) ( 8 ) bytes to &buffer[sizeof(len_A)] ( 8 )

---

Note that this does not copy the bytes in the same order as the OP's algorithm. It was not clear to me if that was required. See comments below.

Comment: Does this deal with the byte-order reversal that the original code tries to do, copying the data from `((uint8_t *)&len_A)[0]` to `buffer[7]`, etc?

Comment: Jonathan has a good point. No, it doesn't. I wasn't sure that was intentional by the OP.

Comment: It's fair to be unsure about whether it was deliberate; I'm not sure either — but it is probably worth mentioning.

Comment: There's no need for parentheses around the expression of `sizeof` here. For variables, doing `sizeof len_A`, etc. works too (and personally I think it's more readable).

Comment: @netcoder: I disagree with your choice; your comment is technically correct. Using `sizeof(whatever)` is uniform and works for both types and expressions, and is simpler to remember and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems very complex.  Why not try to copy the memory directly (assuming that your data is aligned appropriately, which you can ensure e.g. via `aligned_alloc()`):

```
((uint64_t *)buffer)[0] = len_A
((uint64_t *)buffer)[1] = len_C
```

Which one is `len_C` and which one is `len_C` depends on the machine's endianness (if `len_A` is the more significant value, you want the above solution iff you are big-endian.  If `len_C` is the more significant value, you want the above solution iff you are little-endian.)  Otherwise, swap `len_A` and `len_C` in the above.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `buffer` is sufficiently well aligned that you won't get a bus error with that.  Most of the time you'll be fine, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler:  There can be, depending on context.  You could use `memcpy()` etc. in those cases, but in practice you can _usually_ guarantee the alignment through suitable allocation.